# HTML emails sends as plain text with PHP

Tags: php, email

I have this code to send an email via PHP:

```
// Prepare email.
$headers = "From: Mi9 Vault <info@mi9vault.com.au>\r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1";

$msg = file_get_contents($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/edm/confirmation.html');
$msg = str_replace('{first_name}', $contact["First Name"], $msg);


// Send email
mail($contact["Email Address"], "Your Mi9 Registration is Confirmed", $msg, $headers);
```

`confirmation.html` is a HTML email that we've set up.

I've never had any trouble with the above PHP code for sending emails before, however all I can seem to get back is an email containing all of the HTML rather than an actual HTML formatted email.

Basically I get an email with this as the content:

```
MIME-Version: 1.0

Content-type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1
Message-Id: <20120418080325.C643B407EF@ds3219.dreamservers.com>
Date: Wed, 18 Apr 2012 01:03:25 -0700 (PDT)

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    </head>
    <body>
        .....
```

I have the same PHP code on another website with the same host and it works fine...

Comment: I've had this problem before, and solved it by playing around with the placement of `\r\n`. You might want to try Dante's solution.

Comment: Actually inline HTML is only ever going to work with a very lax (non-compliant) user agent. You might get this to display as you want in your email client when you've fixed the newline issue in the ehaders, but you should be using a 7-bit transfer encoding and the html should be marked as mime inline content

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems from that somehow there are extra line breaks between each two lines of your headers.  How it manages to happen, I'm not sure, as your code doesn't put them there. It's possible that the receiving mail server is messed up somehow and interprets `\r\n` as two line breaks instead of one.  To start with, I would remove `\r` leaving only `\n` in and see what happens.  I know this is not proper per RFC - but start with that.

To make you feel better, I am using a very similar code - and the email gets delivered correctly.

Comment: I took the `\r\n` off the first line (with the `From:`) and now it works perfectly.... That is extremely odd.

Comment: @MartyWallace Oh, by the way, try adding `\r\n\r\n` to the last line of the header instead of taking away `\r` - maybe it gets confused by the missing double-end-of-line at the end of the headers

Comment: Just came accros the same problem and indeed solved it by removing the  `\r` . Thanks for this :-)

Answer (score 2):

You don't tell which platform you're running on and which mailer is mail() using. It seems that the mailer you're using is expecting \n to be the separator. You can use PHP_EOL instead of \r\n or \n, and in that case it would use the line separator used in running platform.

For a linux/unix system,

> Line breaks in headers should be the native line endings for the
>   system on which PHP is running.
>
> The mail() function is not talking to an SMTP server, so RFC2822 does
>   not apply here. mail() is talking to a command line program on the
>   local system, and it is reasonable to expect that program to require
>   system-native line breaks.

([source](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=15841))

In the long run, consider using mail() alternatives that have several similar issues generally sorted out. mail() is a very "raw" function that has several gotchas, including header injection. These kind of problems are already solved in, for example, [Swift Mailer](http://swiftmailer.org/) or [PHPMailer](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Try changing :

```
$headers = "From: Mi9 Vault <info@mi9vault.com.au>\r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1";
```

to

```
$headers = 'From: Mi9 Vault <info@mi9vault.com.au>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

try to remove the html and head tag from you html email, just put simple html for content no need for adding extra tags of HTML, and Body
start you html tags after body start tag

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem and I solved it simply by supplying $headers as an array instead of concatenated string with manually added line breaks and carriage returns.

```
$headers = array(
    'From' => "Mi9 Vault <info@mi9vault.com.au>",
    'MIME-Version' => '1.0',
    'Content-type' => "text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1"
);
```

It worked like a charm.